# spring boot log file being overwritten on restart

Tags: spring-boot

I'm using https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html to start my spring-boot application on ubuntu 14.04 and it's working great except my log file gets overwritten whenever I restart the app.  Probably it's something simple... but how can I configure that behaviour?  I'm just using the default console logging to /var/log/app_name.log.  If I pass in the logback "--logging.file=..." config to the init script, it logs both to the default as well as this file and this file doesn't get overwritten.  Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html this should help you with whatever you are trying to do. Probably you need to use logback or log4j to achieve the functionality of log rolls.

Comment: What version of Spring Boot are you using? As of 1.3.1.RELEASE it should append rather than overwriting. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/2b5b7cd81e1103a41e5602b1a42fbd8bc00eb126 for details.

Comment: Interesting - I'm using 1.3.3.RELEASE

Comment: Ha, I was actually using 1.3.0.RELEASE - thank you!